# Call functions in a specific order

Tags: c++

I have 5 functions that I'd like to be called one after the other and I'm not sure how to do so.

```
if(room.at(y) == 9) puzzle1();
```

My idea was that after the user solves the first puzzle the second would be called and so on until all are solved but, I have no idea how to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to implement a bit clearer? Perhaps post a small code that you are trying to implement? Does the condition check done all the time or is it done once?

Comment: Instead of having names like `puzzle1`, `puzzle2` and so on, store your puzzles in a way that allows you to access them by an index. For example, you can use an array of objects that store information about each level. Otherwise, you're going to have to hard-code all the function calls one-by-one since you can't loop over function names.

Answer (score 2):

The statements in a C++ program are executed in a sequential manner unless the program is employing some kind of asynchronous approach (e.g. multi-threading, co-routines, async tasks, etc.). Therefore, you need to list the function calls in a sequence.

For example:

```
start_puzzle_1();
start_puzzle_2();
// ...
start_puzzle_N();
```

Or, if you're trying to start a puzzle when a previous one is solved, you could do that like this:

```
if ( start_puzzle_1() == false )
{
    // in case puzzle is not complete
    // return an error value or handle
    // it as per your requirements
    return some_error_value;
}

// the above puzzle is complete
// continue to next puzzle
if ( start_puzzle_2() == false )
{
    return some_error_value;
}

// and so on...
```

In above case, your functions should be Boolean i.e. they must return `true` on successful completion of a puzzle and `false` otherwise.